# OSX "._" prefixed file names

Tags: macos, filesystems

when i name a file with prefix "._" it just disappear, altrought, other "." beginning files are still visible

what are "._" and how can i see them in finder?

Note: i did enable to see files beginning with "." such as ".DS_Store"

Comment: There's some good coverage of dot underscore files here - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them